# Connection timeout on Elasticsearch parallel_bulk

Tags: python-2.7, elasticsearch

I am trying to import a large amount of data using Elasticsearch parallel_bulk.
This is my Index structure:

```
{
    "_index" : "myindex",
    "_type" : domain,
    "_id" : md5(email),
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "purchase_date" : purchase_date,
      "amount" : amount,
    }
}
```

And this is my python code:

```
def insert(input_file):
    paramL = []

    with open(input_file) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.rstrip()

            fields = line.split(',')
            purchase_date = fields[0]
            amount = fields[1]
            email = fields[2]               

            id_email = getMD5(email)

            doc = {
                "email": email,
                "purchase_date": purchase_date,
                "amount": amount _date
            }

            ogg = {
                '_op_type': 'index',
                '_index': index_param,
                '_type': doctype_param,
                '_id': id_email,
                '_source': doc
            }

            paramL.append(ogg)    

            if len(paramL) > 500000:
                for success, info in helpers.parallel_bulk(client=es, actions=paramL, thread_count=4):
                    if not success:
                        print "Insert failed: ", info

                # empty paramL if size > 5.000.000
                del paramL[:]
```

The file contains 42.644.394 rows and I thinked to insert data each time the list "paramL" is about 5.000.000 elements.
So, when I run the script, it inserts about 436.226 values until it crashes with the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test-2-0.py", line
>   133, in 
>       main()   File "test-2-0.py", line 131, in main
>       insert(args.file)   File "test-2-0.py", line 82, in insert
>       for success, info in helpers.parallel_bulk(client=es, actions=paramL, thread_count=4):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/**init**.py",
>   line 306, in parallel_bulk
>       _chunk_actions(actions, chunk_size, max_chunk_bytes, client.transport.serializer)   File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 668, in next
>       raise value elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionTimeout: ConnectionTimeout caused by -
>   ReadTimeoutError(HTTPConnectionPool(host=u'127.0.0.1', port=9200):
>   Read timed out. (read timeout=10))

I also tried to increase timeout passing it in Elasticsearch constructor

```
es = Elasticsearch(['127.0.0.1'], request_timeout=30)
```

but the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Sincerly I never do a bulk import with so many docs to indicize. I don't know why this error appears. In your case I suggest to not create a list -paramL - but to manage your data with a generator function - as described as best pratice for large bulk ingest in the elastic forum by an elastic developer here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/helpers-parallel-bulk-in-python-not-working/39498/3 . Something like this:

```
def insert(input_file):

    with open(input_file) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.rstrip()

            fields = line.split(',')
            purchase_date = fields[0]
            amount = fields[1]
            email = fields[2]               

            id_email = getMD5(email)

            doc = {
                "email": email,
                "purchase_attack": purchase_date,
                "amount _relevation": amount _date
            }

            yield {
                '_op_type': 'index',
                '_index': index_param,
                '_type': doctype_param,
                '_id': id_email,
                '_source': doc
            }



for success, info in helpers.parallel_bulk(client=es, actions=insert(input_file), thread_count=4):
    if not success:
        print "Insert failed: ", info
```

You can increase the space dedicated to elastic in java virtual machine editing this file `/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options`
 To allocate 2 GB of RAM, you should change - if your machine has 4 GB, you should keep almost 1 GB to the system, so you could allocate max 3 gb:

```
# Xms represents the initial size of total heap space
# Xmx represents the maximum size of total heap space

 -Xms2g
 -Xmx2g
```

Then you have to restart the service

```
sudo service elasticsearch restart
```

And try again. Good luck

Comment: Hi @luponaoide, I customized your suggestion (in my previous question). I had to put "parallel_bulk" function in that way because otherwise the script crashed when paramL exceeded about 7.000.000 of collected values.
In fact, originally I used a logic similar to yours, but as explained it crashes.

Comment: hi @bit  Have you try using a generator, as in my answer, without using paramL?

Comment: hi @lupanoide, I also tried using a generator (as in your example).
This time I managed to insert 1.748.976 records (out of 42.644.394). So, the script is still running, but the count of records is still 1748976...
In this paste I attached the logs: https://pastebin.com/2TDcs8R6

Comment: Ciao @bit - I'm italian too - di Roma, so I understand well your log - connessione interrotta dal corrispondente , in the english version is connection reset by peer. This is a very annoying exception - not an error - because you can most of the times just ignore this exception. It can be related to a lot of situations, so should be better ask for help in the official elastic forum, that is monitored by the elastic developers. However, it seems that the system is really under pressure. If you can allocate more ram to elasticseach - in case I will show you how to do, I will try in this way

Comment: and I'm from Rome too...ti devo un caffè allora! XD
I would try to increase the performance.
this is the current configuration:
- Intel Xeon 3199MHz
- RAM 4GB
- swap 4GB

Comment: @bit I've upgraded my answer with the instructions for increase RAM for ES. Per il caffé volentieri, eddaje!  XD la cosa migliore sarebbe consigliarmi alla tua società qualora gli servisse un altro sviluppatore python - elastic. È davvero un casino cambiar lavoro qui!

Comment: reading on the internet seems that this error could be encouraged by a timeout clause. So please remove request_timeout=30